# Does a morphism that is constant on fibers factor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a morphism $\varphi:Z\to Y$  over $X$, where $X,Y,Z$ are all varieties over an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $q:Z\to X$ be the structure morphism. Suppose that $q$ is smooth and $\varphi$ is constant on the fibers of $q$. Then is there a morphism $\rho:X\to Y$  such that $\varphi=\rho\circ q$?

Comment: I think you want a properness assumption. Otherwise take $Z = Y = \mathbb{A}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^1 = X$), with $\varphi$ the identity and $q$ and the structure morphism of $Y$ the inclusion maps.

Comment: How about assuming $q$ is surjective?

Comment: Can't you just fix @JakeLevinson example to be surjective by taking a disjoint union with a point? With properness hypotheses this is basically the Rigidity Lemma as in Mumford's book on abelian varieties, isn't it?